# Find the two longest strings from a list || or the second longest list in PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, find

I'd like to know how i can find the two longest strings from a list(array) of strings or how to find the second longest string from a list. thanks

Comment: Do you want to do it for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the standard [heapq module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/heapq.html):

```
>>> lst = ['hello', 'blah', 'boo', 'braininess']
>>> heapq.nlargest(2, lst, key=len)
['braininess', 'hello']
```

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way to do this is use the `sorted()` function by using another built-in function `len`  as the `key` argument as follows;

```
>>> foo = ['dddd', 'ccc', 'bb', 'a', 'eeeee']
>>> sorted(foo, key=len)[-2]
'dddd'
```

or if you need the two longest:

```
>>> sorted(foo, key=len)[-2:]
['dddd', 'eeeee']
```

Answer (score 1):

If a is your list of strings, then a.sort(key=len) will sort your list of strings by their length.  The longest would be a[-1], and the second longest would be a[-2].
`

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ['123', '12345', '12']
l.sort(key=lambda item: len(item))
l.[-1] # longest
l.[-2] # second longest
```

Comment: If you were to use a lambda, you might as well do ``-len(item)`` to get them in descending order for more normal access, however, it would be easier just to give the ``len`` builtin as the ``key`` argument.

Comment: Thanks Lattyware - I didn't know that. I'll take a note.