# How to get few specific strings from a list of string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a list of strings and a function getVowel.
This function return the number of vowels present in the string.
Here is the sample code.

```
s = "hello ,this is a string"
no = getVowel(s)
lis = []
lis.append(s)
```

suppose I have got n no of string in the list lis.
How can I  get the top 3 string  with maximum no of vowels in them.

Comment: What is the content of `getVowel`?

Comment: is it relevant to question ?

Comment: Yes, since `getVowel` is supposed to be doing the work of finding the number of vowels.

Comment: yes its doing its work perfectly .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sorted(lis, key=lambda x:getVowel(x), reverse=True)[:3]`

Something like that. BTW, per Python code conventions the correct name of the function should be get_vowel.

Comment: better to use `heapq.nlargest()` for this (rather than `sorted()`)

Comment: debatable. `heapq` is a good option if you want to add more elements to the structure dynamically. Performance-wise `sorted` is sorting faster than `heapq`.

Comment: For a small values of `n` (`n=3` here), `heapq` is better, that is the whole point of this function

Comment: Thanks a lot @Georgi Karadjov .

Comment: Even if this is true (not really sure, should profile it) - `heapq` is a binary heap - you should use such structures only when you need them, the chances are it's not necessary in this case. If we assume that `heapq` is indeed faster - the rule of thumb is to not over-engineer the solution - you need top 3, sort it and get top 3. Don't let the perfect be the enemy of the good.

Answer (score 0):

based on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9887456/4671300

```
from heapq import nlargest
results = nlargest(3, lis, key=getVowel)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your function *getVowel* is indeed working, try the following:

```
sorted(lis, key=lambda x: getVowel(x), reverse=True)[:3]
```

*sorted* documentation : https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted

Answer (score 0):

It would be more efficient to take the *last three* elements from the `sorted` list rather than reversing it, then taking the *first three*.

To do this, just index with `[-3:]` as so:

```
sorted(lis, key=lambda I: getVowel(i))[-3:]
```